# How do you form a sentence to say that a person is very particular and critique in his purchases?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

this kind of people are actually those who will search for reviews or look at a product/content for a long time before they purchase it.

Comment: I think you are (or probably should be) asking not about how to form a sentence but about what word you can use for such a person. If not, the question is probably unclear or too broad.

Comment: Before your question is put on hold, be aware that the adjective you are looking for is "critical". Critique can be used and misused as a noun or a verb (criticism and criticize are better) but not as an adjective (yet).

Answer (score 1):

"Bob was a careful comparison shopper; every purchase was subject to scrutiny and extended deliberation."

In the US "comparison shopper" would be a good neutral term for someone who looks at different prices and features before buying. Alone, "comparison shopper" does not have a negative meaning.

If you want to imply that comparison shopping is annoying you might try to explain why. Is Bob annoying because he's slow to make a decision? Is he annoying because he's cheap? Is he rude to retail staff?

"Bob conducted a CSI-like forensic investigation before purchasing anything. By the time he was done researching, half the products he wanted were already obsolete."

"Bob was an irritating niggler about every aspect of a sale."

"Salespeople at the electronics store asked to take breaks when they saw Bob walk in."

Answer (score 0):

I'd try "thorough": [Oxford dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/thorough). But there's synonyms depending on what you want to insist on :

rigorous, in-depth, exhaustive, thoroughgoing, minute, detailed, close, meticulous, scrupulous, assiduous, conscientious, painstaking, methodical, careful, sedulous, complete, comprehensive, elaborate, full, intensive, extensive, widespread, sweeping, searching, all-embracing, all-inclusive

So you might try: "you are really thorough when you shop". But you might have to adjust on the level of politeness if it's an elder or someone you need to respect.

source : oxforddictionaries.com

Answer (score 0):

Such a person is **choosy**.

> Adjective: **choosy** (choosier,choosiest)  choo-zee
>
> Difficult to please
>
> "A handsome boy was at home there who was extremely choosy and did not care for any of the girls";
>
> - choosey
>
> Derived forms: choosier, choosiest
>
> See also: fastidious

-- [WordWeb](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/405081/how-do-you-form-a-sentence-to-say-that-a-person-is-very-particular-and-critique)